# NOAUTH Authentication required

Tags: apache, redis

After i configured redis with password protected i get below error

```
Exception Occured 
Exception Message --> NOAUTH Authentication required.
Exception Cause --> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: NOAUTH Authentication required.
File Name : SecurityInterceptor.java    
Class Name : org.tcs.com.security.filter.SecurityInterceptor
Method Name : doFilter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your password property to the  block in your Tomcat context.xml..

Answer (score 12):

> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException

indicates that **jedis** (a java Redis client) is used to connect with Redis server.

> "NOAUTH Authentication required error"

indicates that the jedis connection requires password for authentication.

The following java code snippet shows how the password could be set:

```
JedisShardInfo shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo(redisHost, redisPort);
shardInfo.setPassword(redisPassword);
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(shardInfo);
jedis.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

The message is misleading. Proposal is

> Error NOAUTH - Authentication required

Answer (score 1):

```
String cacheHostname = "your cash host";
String cachekey = "your cash primary key";
JedisShardInfo shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo(cacheHostname, 6379);
shardInfo.setPassword(cachekey);
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(shardInfo);
jedis.auth(cachekey);
jedis.connect();
System.out.println( "Cache Response : " + jedis.ping());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public JedisPool(final Config poolConfig, final String host, int port,
        int timeout, final String password) {
    this(poolConfig, host, port, timeout, password, Protocol.DEFAULT_DATABASE);
}
```

This method maybey help you.